# Record is not getting update in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have saved data in database. I am trying to update data. 
But record is not getting update.

If I debug the update function it shows the values i have entered. But when I retrieve the data it dose not show updated values.

What's wrong?

update function in helper class

```
public int updateEvent(EventData event) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE,event.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_FROM_DATE,event.getFromDate());
    values.put(KEY_TO_DATE,event.getToDate());
    values.put(KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK,event.getDayOfWeek());
    values.put(KEY_LOCATION,event.getLocation());
    values.put(KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME,event.getNotificationTime());


    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
           new String[] { String.valueOf(event.getId()) });

}
```

updating in activity:

```
 if (editMode) {

                    eventData.setTitle(title.getText().toString());
                    eventData.setFromDate(showFromTime.getText().toString());
                    eventData.setToDate(showToTime.getText().toString());
                    eventData.setDayOfWeek(selectDay.getText().toString());
                    eventData.setLocation(mAutocompleteView.getText().toString());
                    eventData.setNotificationTime(notifyTime.getText().toString());

                    db.updateEvent(eventData);
                }
                else {
                    db.addEvent(new EventData(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, dayOfWeek, location, notificationTime));

                }
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

                finish();

            }
```

Thank you..

Comment: What is returned from `db.update(...)`? Do you get 0 or a positive number? That is the number of rows affected by the update to at least make sure something is updated.

Comment: If `KEY_ID` is a numeric type, then pass an `Integer`, not a `String`.

Comment: Where does `event.getId()` come from?

Comment: Its not showing any number. When I have debug all the values are shown on   return db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
               new String[] { String.valueOf(event.getId() : 1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4548} "notification" -> "10 Minutes before "
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4547} "dayofweek" -> "Mon"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4549} "title" -> "gfdgs"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4550} "location" -> "Llandilo, New South Wales, Australia"
4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4551} "dateto" -> "10:31 AM"
5 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4552} "datefrom" -> "09:31 AM"

Comment: I have EventData class with getter setter methods.@ Hrundi V. Bakshi

Comment: Maybe try setting the result of `db.updateEvent(eventData)` to an int and check what the value is.  That will show how many rows updated, update method looks ok so perhaps your id is not set/get correctly.

Comment: How to set it to int? @Robbie188

Comment: `int rowsUpdated = db.updateEvent(eventData);`

Comment: Its showing 0 . Whts wrong @Robbie188

Comment: Are you sure you set the id on `event`? What is `event.getId()` returning?

Comment: It returns 0. It dose not get increment?

Comment: What if you try `eventData.getId()`, instead?

Comment: Your problem must be that your instance of EventData does not have the record id set properly.  Are you definitely calling `eventData.setId()` with the correct id?

Comment: event is an object  of eventData only. @ Hrundi V. Bakshi